# How to get the id variable from firebase function trigger?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
  export const product = functions.firestore
    .document("shops/{shopId}/products/{prodId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        let productId = snap.id;

        
    })
```

I want to access `shopId` from this on create trigger. Is there any way to get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to access the wildcards:

```
  export const product = functions.firestore
    .document("shops/{shopId}/products/{prodId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        let productId = snap.id;
        let shopId   = context.params.shopId;
    })
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Comment: Thank you . But i found a way too `let shopId = snap.ref.path.split("/")[1];`